# Unable to run release pipeline for synpase : PublicNetworkAccessDenied

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have created a dev to qa release pipeline. Previously public access enabled so it worked fined but now disabled the public access to synapse workspace then it throws the following error

[image: 2]

I have created the private endpoint and also added the service principal.

Comment: Check this document, it may help you to get your issue resolved: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network.md

Comment: Hi Navin, Thank You for the response. I need to setup self hosted agent. And that worked for me. Microsoft hosted agent won't be able to reach the resource using private endpoints.